# How to put multiple predictors in a general linear mixed model in R

Tags: r

I am making a general linear mixed model in which the data is nested into bird nests. After doing alot of wider reading all I can find is:

```
GLMM1<-lmer(tarsusl~predact+(1|pop), data=nestdat)
```

When what I need is to account for predator activity and invertebrate density while accounting for nestID.

How do I put all these parameters into the code to give a general linear mixed model? Thanks

Comment: what are you mostly interested in as a predictor of tarsus? are predator activity and invertebrate density dependent on NestID? is 'pop' population? you can add more than one random effect and have `lmer(tarsusl~predact + invert.density +(1|pop) + (1|nestID), data = nestdat)`

Comment: @Roasty247 thank you for your response. This has allowed me to do a GLMM random intercept model. To do an intercept and slope model what do I need to type in the brackets? eg. (1|nestID)

Comment: I've never used them so not 100%, but I think for a random slope models, rather than varying the random effect around the intercept (which is "`1`" in `(1|nestID)`) you can vary it according to the slope of the predictor in question. e.g 
 `lmer(tarsusl~predact + invert.density +(1|pop) + (invert.density|nestID), data = nestdat)`   https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-the-most-of-mix-models-with-random-slopes/ this might be helpful?